# MIPS jal not remembering position

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm currently translating a program into MIPS assembly language and currently my program runs into an infinite loop currently with this segment of code

```
expoZero:
#returns 1
li $s3, 1

jr $ra

checkEven:

#Check if base is even or odd
addi $sp, $sp, -8
sw $ra, 4($sp)
sw $s0, 0($sp)
andi $s2,$s0,0x1

lw $s0, 0($sp)
lw $ra, 4($sp)
addi $sp, $sp 8
jr $ra


even:
addi $sp, $sp, 4
sw $ra,0($sp)

#if the base is even it performs a^(b/2)*a^(b/2)
move $a0,$s0        #$a0 = base
move $a1,$s1        #$a1 = exponent

srl $a1,$a1,1       #$a1/2
j power
move $s4,$v0

move $a0,$s4
move $a1,$s4
jal multiply
#returns result
addi $s3, $s3, 1

jr $ra

odd:
#if the base is odd it performs a*a^((b-1)/2)*a^((b-1)/2)

#returns result
addi $s3, $s3, 1

jr $ra

power:

#If exponent $s1 is equal to zero returns 1 as result
beq $s1,$zero,expoZero

jal checkEven

#if base is even go to even
beq $s2,$zero,isEven

#if base is odd go to odd
j odd


multiply:
addi $sp, $sp -24
sw $ra, 20($sp)
sw $s0, 16($sp)
sw $s1, 12($sp)
sw $s2, 8($sp)
sw $s3, 4($sp)
sw $s4, 0($sp)

#set result equal to zero
move $s3,$zero

#test for a > 0
slt $t2,$a0,$zero   #a < 0

loop:
#while (a<0)
beq $t2,$zero,exit
add $s3,$s3,$a1     #result += b
addi $a0,$a0,-1     #a--

j loop

exit:
lw $s4, 0($sp)
lw $s3, 4($sp)
lw $s2, 8($sp)
lw $s1, 12($sp)
lw $s0, 16($sp)
lw $ra, 20($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 24
j power
```

It currently runs through an infinite loop from the even and then when it jumps back to power it reset even so instead of running through multiply it goes back into power.

Comment: At the start of `even` you're pushing `$ra` on the stack, but you never seem to pop it.

Comment: @Michael see I made a mistake with even and addi $sp, $sp, 4 supposed to be -4 and added a lw for $ra, however what do you mean by pop it

Comment: "Push" = decrement sp, store to (sp). "Pop" = load from (sp), increment sp.

Comment: @Michael I updated it and added the lw to pop it however it still seems to get stuck in an infinite loop where I mention in even and power

Comment: Use a simulator like SPIM or MARS to single-step through the code and see what happens.

Comment: The code is incomplete, a fragment of code.  How are we supposed to reason over this?  From an execution perspective, where does the code start?  Who calls what, especially as a test case, i.e. the rest of the program?  I can't tell what labels are supposed to be functions and what are snippets of code belonging to some other function, the way the snippets are interleaved.  You need to get some discipline / methodology over the notion of functions vs. labels.  It is good that you are translating a working program, so go back to that and be more rigorous about function units in assembly.

Comment: You might start by translating the simplest functions using the standard calling convention, the simple functions that don't call other functions (aka leaf functions).  Test calling them, then translate the larger functions.

Comment: As for `jal` not remembering where to go back to, it is not `jal`'s fault if your program doesn't keep the return address for each function straight.  That's part of the rigor around function units that this code is missing.  Functions should have a clear entry point, and a corresponding clear exit points.  They should only call each other, never `j` to each other.  They should follow the standard calling conventions for parameter passing (modulo advanced optimization techniques).

Comment: Assembly allows for all manner of bizarre and confusing and error prone control flow constructs. Favor the well-reasoned concept of functions, and functions that call functions instead.